# Revert file to an older version Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

Something as simple as the title.
Today all I did with my work was bad, I want to remove all.
Using the "history" tab I can perfectly see the version I want. How can I get It back? I can perfectly see it, compare it, but I cannot find an easy way to get it back.
Just delete all the changes I see after that... How do I rollback?

As it sys [here](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/track-changes-in-your-latex-documents-2014-03-31), it should be possible to do it:

> **Revert any file back to any point in time.** You can undo any changes,
> in any file, so there's no need to worry about making any mistakes.

Comment: I tried manual restoring of the project to a previous version by download and re-upload of the files, but all the comments and options to accept or reject changes are gone. Is there any way to bring them back? And how has such a feature as important as restoring older versions not been reimplemented in 2.5 years since this question was first asked? Is Overleaf abandonware?

Comment: Copy and paste onto a text file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/570-tip-of-the-week-project-versioning-and-history) link:

> This article is about a feature in Overleaf v1. Overleaf v2 lets you
> label versions of your project, but you can't yet restore them.
> Restoring from a labeled version will be coming back to Overleaf v2
> in the future. Until then, you can download a zip file of the labeled
> version or use copy and paste to restore content for individual files.

What I did, because I have the premium version and linked to dropbox, is download the `zip` version and extract items in the folder where the project is (`Dropbox/Apps/Overleaf`) making "yes to all" to the replace pop-up.

For the non-premium users, I believe they should do it with the web interface uploading from the computer and replacing the files.

Comment: Hi Agustin, Tom from Overleaf Support here. What you found out is correct -- we currently do not have a way how to do direct reverts. When a smaller revert is needed, it's posisble to simply replace the file(s) contents. The edited files are highlighted in the History when comparing versions. When a large revert is needed, we recommend starting a new project. Sorry for the limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Agustin that the Dropbox or GitHub integration is a nice feature, indeed it is not free. However, a simple workaround is to check the file history in the project. Everytime you press Ctrl+S, a file snapshot is created and a version log entry is written. Overleaf logs who has made which change in which file.

Go to the upper right corner and click "History" button, which is in between the "Submit" button and the "Chat" button. Then the history log of the project becomes visible.
In the "single version" view you can see the changes in one snapshot, in the "Compare to another version" view you can select a version far earlier and see all changes made since then.

Comment: Indeed, I knew about this feature, the question is not to compare nor to see old version but how make an old version the current one. For example, if my current version/head is version 99, now replace it with version 53... or in other words, make version 100 equal to version 53.
It would be nice btw to have something like git where you could delete, for example, only changes of a specific version like 60.